# Why use a function parameter 'foo' in this way: *(&foo)?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

A code snippet in Linux kernel 0.12 use a function parameter like this:

```
int do_signal(int signr, int eax /* other parameters... */) {
    /* ... */

    *(&eax) = -EINTR;

    /* ... */
}
```

The purpose of the code is to put -EINTR to the memory where eax lives, but I can not tell why it won't work if just assigning to eax:

```
eax = -EINTR
```

How would the compiler make a difference between ***eax*** and ***(&eax)**?

Comment: Can you provide us the link to that kernel source?? or add full definition of the function (if its not too long).

Comment: It could be to prevent the compiler from using a register for eax and force it to use memory on the stack.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: Nice!!! You should write it down as it's probably the correct answer (the name `eax` actually insinuates that this is the reason).

Comment: @barakmanos Shafik Yaghmour has posted an excellent answer with references to relevant sections in the standard, so I'll just upvote his answer instead.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One possible intention could be to keep the `eax` variable out of a register. If we look at the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) we see that section `6.5.3.2` *Address and indirection operators*  <s>says (*emphasis mine*):</s>

> The unary & operator yields the address of its operand. [...]If the operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that
>   operator nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is **as if both
>   were omitted**, except that **the constraints on the operators still apply**
>   and the result is not an lvalue.[...]

in footnote *87* it says (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> Thus, &*E is equivalent to E (even if E is a null pointer), and
>   &(E1[E2]) to ((E1)+(E2)). **It is always true that if E is a function
>   designator or an lvalue that is a valid operand of the unary &
>   operator, *&E is a function designator or an lvalue equal to E**.

we find the following constraint on `& operator`:

> The operand of the unary & operator shall be either a function
>   designator, the result of a [] or unary * operator, or an lvalue that
>   designates an object that is not a bit-field **and is not declared with
>   the register storage-class specifier.**

Which makes sense since we can not take the address of a register and so by performing an *address of* operation they may have been trying to prevent the compiler from performing the operations completely in registers and ensure that data in specific memory locations are modified.

As ouah points out this does not prevent the compiler from optimizing what is effectively a *no-op* away but as documented in [GCC hacks in the Linux kernel](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gcc-hacks/). Linux has relied on many `gcc` extensions and considering that `0.12` is a very old kernel `gcc` may have guaranteed that behavior or may have by accident reliably worked that way but I can not find any documentation that says so.

Comment: +1, this is a nice answer but what prevents the compiler to still use a register for `eax` and consider `*&` as a no-op? It could well be a hack for a specific compiler.

Comment: Nice answer, indeed. But the operand of `&` isn't the result of unary `*` here, it's the other way round (we have `*&eax`, not `&*eax`) and I cannot find an analogous guarantee for `*` in the standard. Maybe this partially answers Ouah's concerns?

Comment: I also want to add that the absence of the `register` doesn't say anything to the compiler. The constraint applies to the declaration, but not to where the value is actually is placed. As far as I know, there is no way to guarantee where the value goes in standard C99, even the `register` keyword itself is merely a suggestion to the compiler. Maybe if the address is actually used, then it has to go to the memories, but I'm not sure that optimizations can't change that.

Comment: @ouah I was speculating here, Linux has been very reliant on gcc extensions and so I was guessing this was the case here as well.

Comment: @mafso good catch, I messed up the ordering, I struck it through since I can not prove it works the other way either.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour `*&` appears as a footnote in c11, 6.5.3.2p4: "It is
always true that if E is a function designator or an lvalue that is a valid operand of the unary & operator, *&E is a function designator or an lvalue equal to E."

Comment: @ouah I missed that, it is footnote `87` in C99.

Answer (score 30):

The old Linux you posted was trying to perform an very fragile hack. The function was defined like this:

```
int do_signal(long signr,long eax,long ebx, long ecx, long edx, long orig_eax,
    long fs, long es, long ds,
    long eip, long cs, long eflags,
    unsigned long * esp, long ss)
```

The function arguments don't actually represent arguments to the function (except `signr`), but the values that calling function (a kernel interrupt/exception handler written in assembly) preserved on the stack before calling `do_signal`. The `*(&eax) = -EINTR` statement is meant to modify the preserved value of EAX on the stack. Similarly the statement `*(&eip) = old_eip -= 2` is meant to modify the return address of the calling handler. After `do_signal` returns the handler pops the first 9 "arguments" off the stack restoring them to the named registers. It then executes an `IRETD` instruction that pops the remaining arguments off the stack and return to user mode.

Needless to say this hack is incredibly unreliable. It's dependent on the compiler generating code exactly the way they expected it to. I'm surprised it even worked the GCC compiler of the era, I doubt it was long before GCC introduced an optimization that broke it.

Comment: I'm surprised even old `gcc` versions would behave differently with `eax = -EINTR` and `*(&eax) = -EINTR` and optimizations enabled.

Comment: Yeah, it's really trouble to compile old kernels on modern system, but somebody has get it done, see [Oldlinux.org](http://www.oldlinux.org)

Comment: Older versions of GCC wouldn't put things in regsiters if you took the address of them. (Note that this behaviour isn't required by the standard, only that you can't declare something explictly `register` if you take the address of it.) The compiler might still have eliminated or moved the assignment since its a simple constant and not all the code paths use it.