# What does &variable as a expression mean in c

Tags: c, reference

this is the snippet of a program code :

```
 char authenticated = 0;
 char guard1 = 234;
 char guard2 = 234;
 //more variables initliased...
 char buf[128];

 &authenticated;
 &guard1;
 &guard2;
```

So what does it mean when the reference stands there as a single expression in the program code?

**Edit**: More Context : It's compiled with gcc on a debian server and it's related to a security project, where you can overflow the buf array.

Comment: Perhaps related to [Why use a function parameter 'foo' in this way: *(&foo)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25530115/1708801), I don't think there is enough context.

Comment: `&` is the address operator. `&authenticated` is the address in RAM of the `authenticated` variable. The statement `&authenticated;` (note the `;`) is legal C, but doesn't do anything.

Comment: Out of good reasons i have to assume that it has a purpose.

Comment: the lines `&authenticated;` `&guard1;`, and `&guard2;` do nothing in the code above.  they appear to be either an attempt to force a side effect or value free.

Comment: I'm wondering whether this code is trying to set up a stack frame with some specific values in some specific places. Can you provide more context?

Comment: @templatetypedef I agree which is consistent with the question I linked to but definitely not enough context.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is to cause the compilation to fail if something is wrong. If the code had a lot of sections that were excluded with `#ifdef`s for example, these statements would make sure that the variables are actually defined somewhere.

Comment: The code is only one file and without preprocessor directives such as `#ifdef`

Comment: Can you post assembly of this using the compilation settings that are recommended I am curious about what @templatetypedef said

Comment: I concur with @ShafikYaghmour link that the intent here is to force the compiler to keep the variables on the stack (vs. in registers only) by taking the address of each. Of course, if the code doesn't do anything else with those variables the compiler may well optimize them out completely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that this is for a security project, my guess is that these statements are designed to prevent the compiler from optimizing away the `authenticated`, `guard1`, and `guard2` variables. If these variables aren't used later on in the function, a compliant C compiler could optimize them away, changing the layout of the stack frame for the function call.

Technically speaking, since these statements have no side-effects, the compiler could in principle optimize them away as well. However, the sense I get is that the intended compiler doesn't do this (not that it *couldn't* do it, just that it *can't* do it). That way, the layout of the stack frame will have the `authenticated` variable shielded by two `char` values that are not null terminators, potentially making it a bit trickier to overwrite `authenticated`. Of course, it sounds like your assignment is specifically to change `authenticated`, so it's not foolproof. :-)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Makes sense. Yes the task is to overwrite authenticated. But authenticated and the guards. (There are also random canaries which i left out for simplicity) are all later used to check if their value hasn't changed.

Comment: In K&R C, taking the address of a variable meant that it could not be stored in a register. ISO C relaxes this requirement via the as-if rule; but the compiler that this code was written for might respect that intention.

Comment: However it's not clear to me why the coder didn't write `struct { char guard1; char buf[128]; char guard2; } x;` or similar